# Is the claim that a non conscious entity cannot create a conscious entity valid?

Tags: metaphysics, consciousness, existence-of-god

In a debate I watched online, the theist person claimed that conscious creatures, such as humans, can only be created by a conscious being, because a non conscious being isn't able to give this property to its creations.
Unfortunately, the atheist person didn't ask for a proof to this claim or to demonstrate the reason why this is the case.
Is this a valid claim that can be proven?

Comment: We do not know for sure, but it seems unlikely to be true. There is no physical obstruction to such creation (by evolution, for example) that we know of. Theists take it as an article of faith that only God can endow something with consciousness (or even life). Arguments for it either beg the question or rely on discredited conceptions such as [irreducible complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_complexity).

Comment: All I can think of to reject the claim is the fact that there are levels of consciousness, and it is seems clearly related to the complexity of the brain and how it developed and evolved.

Comment: Also, if the rule is generic, such as a property x can only be given by creators to creations if the creator has it, then this is invalid, as us humans create machines that fly and we can't fly. If it is specific to consciousness, then we don't really know how consciousness really work or how does it arise.

Answer (score 1):

- The proponent claims: Only a conscious being can create other
  conscious beings.
- My reply: Who created the conscious being God?
- The proponent could answer: God is eternal, he/she has not been
  created.
- My reply: From where do you know?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into substance dualism. If our minds cannot be *reduced* to the functioning of their biological matter, then presumably they cannot be *explained* by them either.

For me (and I'm not agreeing with your theist, not really) I struggle to understand what a physical explanation of consciousness would look like. Really, because something seems to be **missing** from any account.

I actually read a fair amount on so called "naturalised phenomenology", which sought to solve that problem, the genie of phenomena themselves, by, appropriately enough, trying to take Husserl's method and make it into something natural.

This is, I think, against the spirit of his philosophy, which was idealist, and deeply anti naturalist at least in method. It came off as quite simple minded, square pegs and round holes.

Whether or not that means we have ***intractable*** problems in naturalising consciousness is a lot less clear. The question surely boils down to whether we can define consciousness in a meaningful way, without recourse to entities or structures which are not natural. Given that some proponents of 'qualia' would go as far as to say that they are *incommunicable* (not just in terms of accepted biological theories), perhaps there will be no true consensus either way (as materialism is highly attractive).

### tl;dr

does it need an "explanation"?

Comment: I wouldn't advise being a brain in a vat anyway, in the same way you wouldn't want to commit evil acts or be overwhelmed by hubris in front of (even fictional) divinities.

Comment: nietzsche definitely seemed to think that at least the experience of pain, if not pleasure, was in some sense incommunicable, that you could not justify the claim you had caused someone else to suffer.

Comment: probably just a figure of speech meant to disguise (?) his own will to power or whatever.